# How to get the exact URL from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, routes, hyperlink

I have a URL in `link_to` in this format:

```
link_to @offer.listing.title, [@offer.listing.user, @offer.listing]
```

which generated something like

```
/users/ID_OF_USER/listings/ID_OF_LISTING
```

But I need the URL in this format:

```
http://www.website.com/users/ID_OF_USER/listings/ID_OF_LISTING
```

I tried something like

```
link_to @offer.listing.title, root_url+[@offer.listing.user, @offer.listing]
```

but ended up with an error. How can I convert the URL in the array into a format with the name of the website?

Answer (score 3):

```
link_to @offer.listing.title, listing_url(@offer.listing.user, @offer.listing)
```